# Is it possible to identify secreted metabolites or secondary metabolites from a gene list?

Tags: bioinformatics, gene-expression, metabolomics

So I have a gene list obtained from differential gene expression analysis of a metabolic disease model, and I was wondering if I can identify metabolites or secondary metabolites that may be produced by some of enzymes or reactions modulated by these genes by bulk.
For example, I know that Ptgds synthesises prostaglandin D2 and it is secreted in urine and plasma, and so on.

However, I don't want to do a whole research on each and every gene separately, rather like a database or a tool that can identify them by just inserting a gene list!

Comment: Obtaining the specific metabolites from genome-wide measurements of transcripts can be somewhat possible, but remains quite challenging, and might not be possible for many organisms because too little is known about them. If the purpose is to get a better idea of the changes in transcriptome without needing to infer specific metabolites (e.g.: if it is sufficient to know if some pathway is up or down regulated) you could do functional gene enrichment analysis instead. Latter can be adopted widely and there are nice tools such as the web-based https://david-d.ncifcrf.gov

Comment: The problem is that we want to identify some biomarkers that are steadily found in urine, plsama or other easily attainable fluids. I already did enrichment analysis and gene ontology along with many others.

Comment: I am currently going through each gene and looking into their pathways to find whether they produce metabolites. It's time consuming and not efficienct I'm afraid.